# Using Testcafe with Appium

Tags: typescript, appium, e2e-testing, browser-automation, testcafe

I'm searching for some time now how to use TestCafe with Appium.

Long story short: testing env is a *node.js* env; automated test script is written in *typescript* using *TestCafe*; the plan is to execute those tests on desktop browsers and on mobile phones.

**Desktop** browsers: this is covered trough *TestCafe* and [testcafe-browser-provider-selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-selenium) and a *Selenium grid* server.

**Mobile** phones: I'm trying to cover this by executing tests on mobiles phones using *TestCafe* along with *Appium*.

Here, the documentation is not easy to find, and I had no luck in doing any progress. I'm interested what do I need to do from Testcafes side, because inside LAN, I can access an already running Appium server, with real devices attached to it.

Is there someone who uses the above tools and would like to share the know how?

PS: I've seen this link already, and it's not helping, as it needs human interaction and it's not fully automated: [QR code suggestion for TestCafe mobile device testing](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-run-test-on-mobile-browser-without-manually-opening-the-url-scanning-qr-code/511/4)

**Later edit**:

using the **testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio** package did not solve the problem, because it has some connections issues. So, I'm back on searching a solution and *I refuse to believe that there is no option for the above scenario*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio](https://github.com/fnlctrl/testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio) plugin. The author claims this provider can connect to an Appium server.

Comment: I did tried out the package you pointed out, but it has some issues from what I see. Thanks again.

Comment: Later edit: it seems that this plugin does the job perfectly, meaning it allows testcafe to connect to an appium server.

Comment: @Eugen: please guide me about exact string which worked for you, like: testcafe webdriverio:chrome:android:emulator-5554 my_first_test.js

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava, sorry, but I stopped working with testcafe for one year at least. I completely forgot what I did in there.